# Missing 'Z' component from points extracted from polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, xyz, nodes

I have polylines which were created with XYZ coordinates and after extracting the points (nodes) I want to export these to a .csv file with their XYZ coordinates. When I try the 'save as' function and specify the layer options 'AS_XYZ' I get the file with all z coordinates as '0'.
Can anyone help me get the missing component?
I know the height data is associated with the shapefiles as they display in 3D correctly, so why can i not retrieve it?

I am using QGIS las palmas on a mac. Also ArcGIS on PC (using XTools), which gives the same problem!

Comment: I would probably import your polyline into GRASS then use [v.out.ogr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.out.ogr.html) to export to CSV.